# Powershell doesn't get the Item exception in a foreach

Tags: powershell

I was tryn to measure the download directorys on a core server where are folderredirections from useres but also some other stuff where are no download directorys.

So tried to catch this exception but it doesnt catch neither the specified one or the catch everything one.

```
$path = "\\Server\folderredirection"
$childitem = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
foreach ($c in $childitem)
{
    $dloads = "$path\$c\Downloads\*"
    Write-Log "------------------------------------------"
        try{
            $files = Get-ChildItem -path $dloads -Recurse
            $Size = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1MB
            $Size = [math]::Round($Size,2)
            if($Size -gt 0)
            {
                Write-Log "$c has worth $Size MB items in downloads"
            }else{
                Write-Log "$c has no items in downloads"
            }
            $totalSize = $totalSize + $Size
        }catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{
            Write-Log "$c has no download dir"
        }catch{
            Write-Log "Unexpected Error while $c"
        }        
    Write-Log "------------------------------------------"
}
```

I dont know if i have a failure in how I execute my task in PW or i tricked myself.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Try adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-ChildItem`. Catch blocks only trigger when there is a terminating exception, and it might be throwing a non-terminating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Catch block to trigger in a [Try..Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) a terminating error must be thrown. `Get-ChildItem` throws a non-terminating error by default for non existent paths. You can force a cmdlet to throw terminating errors for all error by using the `-ErrorAction` switch and setting it to `Stop`. Alternatively you can change the global `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.

This should work:

```
$path = "\\Server\folderredirection"
$childitem = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
foreach ($c in $childitem)
{
    $dloads = "$path\$c\Downloads\*"
    Write-Log "------------------------------------------"
        try{
            $files = Get-ChildItem -path $dloads -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
            $Size = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1MB
            $Size = [math]::Round($Size,2)
            if($Size -gt 0)
            {
                Write-Log "$c has worth $Size MB items in downloads"
            }else{
                Write-Log "$c has no items in downloads"
            }
            $totalSize = $totalSize + $Size
        }catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{
            Write-Log "$c has no download dir"
        }catch{
            Write-Log "Unexpected Error while $c"
        }        
    Write-Log "------------------------------------------"
}
```

Comment: Does this actually stop the script or do the "others" run through as well ?

Comment: No, because you’re inside a try catch so after the catch block has executed it will then carry on. The script would only stop if a terminating error occurs somewhere outside the try block.

Comment: Allright I did a test run now it works perfectly fine. Thank you for the fast and precise answer. Have a nice day